# Ubuntu Touch install failure on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: ubuntu-touch

The command `phablet-flash -b` does not give enough time for my device to reboot into recovery mode before it pushes the phablet zip file across. I tried doing the command again once it finally went into recovery mode giving this result:

```
user/Downloads/phablet-flash/152$ phablet-flash -b
Device detected as /sbin/sh: getprop: not found
Unsupported device, autodetect fails device
```

But I can understand why that didn't work. I tried to manually push the file across myself but then it wouldn't deploy. 
Are there any manual instructions I can perform under terminal to get it to continue once in recovery mode? Or is there a way to magically pause the terminal when it's waiting for the device to reboot into recovery mode? Or where in the code can I change it from, say, `Sleep 5 sec` to `sleep 10 sec`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Either it was a coincidence that it just happened to work this time or I was right that I just had to change the sleep time in the script `/usr/bin/phablet-flash`.

Open `phablet-flash` through terminal (as root so you can edit it)

```
sudo -H gedit '/usr/bin/phablet-flash'
```

and in the area:

```
@adb_errors
def autodeploy(adb, artifact):
    ''' Pushes artifact to devices sdcard and deploys'''
    if not artifact:
        return
    # Can't wait-for-device here
    sleep(15)
    adb.push(artifact, '/sdcard/autodeploy.zip')
    log.info('Deploying Ubuntu')
    adb.reboot(recovery=True)
    log.info('Installation will complete soon and reboot into Ubuntu')
```

I changed

```
sleep(15)
```

to

```
sleep(30)
```

You can then re-run the 'phablet-flash -b' command and it should work

---

Also if any other noobs like me trying to reinstall Android have the problem of deploying:

```
./flash-all.sh
```

and get the error

```
bash: ./flash-all.sh: Permission denied
```

Go to your android distribution folder, open `flash-all.sh` and copy and paste the commands from that script to the terminal and run them separately, simple as.